# Wind Time series in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, time-series

I have 11 time series wich include the values wind direction, wind speed and wind power. What I want to do is an interpolation between each value. Each time series contains 8670 values for every hour of one year. I need to put this 11 time series into QGIS. Each of the 11 time series has to be a "Weather Station" (Point Layer, maybe in a multipoint layer?!) wich include the 8760 values for each hour and the columns direction, speed, power. Furthermore I want to do an interpolation between the 11 "stations". For Example, I want to say "Qgis ==> Raster==> Interpolation ==> choose Station  ==> value "speed" ... The result should be, that Qgis does an interpolation between every station and values of the choosed column.

What I want as a result at the end is an Windmap wich makes clear how many wind power or wind speed is at a speacial location (as you can see in my picture, WRONG VALUES!)

[image]